# react-router not routing to components

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have the following routes:

```
const ThemedApp = () => (
  <MuiThemeProvider>
    <App />
  </MuiThemeProvider>
);

ReactDOM.render((
  <Router history={hashHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={ThemedApp}>
      <Route path="monitor/health" component={Monitor} />
    </Route>
    <Route path="*" component={Page404} />
  </Router>
), document.getElementById('root'));
```

when I access `/monitor/health` I still get the index. Also, when I access `/12312312312` I never get the 404 page, only the index, always the index.

my `App` goes like

```
render() {
    return this.props.children || (
        <div className="App">
          <div className="App-header">
            <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
```

I'm accessing these urls directly in the browser, not through `Link`. I need this `/monitor/health` because devops wants to check this app's availability

Answer (score 0):

The * path should be inside of the "/" path, like this:

```
<Route path="/" component={ThemedApp}>
  <Route path="monitor/health" component={Monitor} />
  <Route path="*" component={Page404} />
</Route>
```

Comment: didn't worked. Only when I hit the url through `<Link>`

Comment: What is provider and store? I'm not using redux/flux